# Memory Leak in Windows Service ( CodeGear C++ XE5 ) Using Indy TIdTCPServer

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, indy10, fastmm

I have CodeGear C++ Builder XE5. Server created with TIdTCPServer, which works nicely.
However memory used by service is growing. I finally managed to include Full version of FastMM4 memory manager and after fiddling with options I found confirmation of memory leakage:

```
13 - 20 bytes: TIdThreadSafeInteger x 1
21 - 36 bytes: TIdCriticalSection x 2, Unknown x 1
53 - 68 bytes: UnicodeString x 1
85 - 100 bytes: Unknown x 21
149 - 164 bytes: Unknown x 21
181 - 212 bytes: Unknown x 2
```

Obviously x1 and x2 don't concern me, however x21 leaks are bad since this is highly used service - each connection bleed 100 and 164 bytes:

more details information states:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 100

This block was allocated by thread 0xD98, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
    8D4743 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8D461D [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8E0F94 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8E0F59 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8DFADA [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8DE722 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8BF045 [Unknown function at @@Searchfilelist@Finalize]
    8C4C90 [Unknown function at @@Searchfilelist@Finalize]
    8D6638 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    775D1C77 [Unknown function at RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb]
    452A45 [@Fastmm4@DebugGetMem$qqri]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown
```

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 164

This block was allocated by thread 0x5394, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
    8D4743 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8D461D [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8E0FD9 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8E0F59 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8DFADA [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8DE722 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    8BF045 [Unknown function at @@Searchfilelist@Finalize]
    8C4C90 [Unknown function at @@Searchfilelist@Finalize]
    8D6638 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
    775D1C77 [Unknown function at RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb]
    452A45 [@Fastmm4@DebugGetMem$qqri]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown

The allocation number is: 125893
```

At this point I am stuck, I don't know where this is coming for since I don't call directly 
Zip_int. Can anyone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

The first two leaks - `TIdThreadSafeInteger` and `TIdCriticalSection` - are well known leaks in Indy that only happen at app shutdown as they are global objects intentionally not freed.  I am surprised to see them in the leak report as Indy registers them with FastMM as known leaks.

The others are not Indy leaks.  Your code has to be allocating something you are not freeing.  The `UnicodeString` leak may be a indication of that, as the most common way to leak a String is if it is a member of a class instance that is not freed. If the leaks are in proportion to the number of connections your server receives, then you are likely allocating something and storing it in `TIdContext`, such as in the `OnConnect` event, and not freeing later, such as in the `OnDisconnect` event.  But you did not show your code.

What I find odd is that the leaks appear to be allocated during unit finalization, not during normal run of the app, but why there are so many `Finalize` calls together, I do not know.  Unless the app's stack trace info ks wrong.  FastMM is not able to report more meaningful info because those units were likely not compiled with debug info enabled.  Do you at least have a .MAP file generated by the compiler for your app?  That helps FastMM resolve function names from memory addresses.

Comment: Well, I was able clean up thing a bit. I found that 100+164 was due to call of creat and errno, i.e. for whatever reason if I call function from stdlib from within thread it leaks 100 + 164 bytes, when I changed it to VCL code FileCreate and GetLastError leaks where gone. At this point I still have 36 byte per every connection

Comment: A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 36
....
8E6850 
775D2E0A [Unknown function at RtlFreeUnicodeString]
775D2E49 [Unknown function at RtlFreeUnicodeString]
775D2E70 [Unknown function at RtlFreeUnicodeString]
775D3360 [Unknown function at RtlFindActivationContextSectionString]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown
This is with TDS file in place where exe is. without it I see different picture:

Comment: ....
8D61F9 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
722B30 [Unknown function at TMethodImplementationIntercept]
8D688F [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
8E6850 [Unknown function at @@Zip_int@Finalize]
775D2E0A [Unknown function at RtlFreeUnicodeString]
775D2E49 [Unknown function at RtlFreeUnicodeString]
775D2E70 [Unknown function at RtlFreeUnicodeString]
775D3360 [Unknown function at RtlFindActivationContextSectionString]

Comment: When `TThread` terminates, it does not free thread-local storage memory used by the C runtime, like for `errno`.  This is a known problem, such as [this bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=117055) and [this bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=93676).

Comment: Oh ! I tracked down 39 bytes to the fact if during  io->ReadBytes(buffer, some size, false); I get an exception due to the fact connection is closed ( which it is ) I get 39 bytes loss, even if I handle exception in catch. If call this first: AContext->Connection->IOHandler->CheckForDataOnSource(2000), I don't get exception and I don't get 39 bytes loss, but service start working slower.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that would leak if an exception is raised.  Something else has to be leaking.  As for the timing, you could check `if not IOHandler->InputBufferIsEmpty` before calling `IOHandler->CheckForDataOnSource()`.